# Server won't receive emails from Instagram

Tags: postfix, mail, mail-server, dovecot

I am having issues receiving emails from instagram to my server domain.

The email works fine (to and from) everywhere else.

Facebook also wouldn't send to a different email using the same domain.

Any ideas areciated. Many thanks

PS: There doesnt seem to be any error messages in the mail.log

I tried this solution but it didnt solve my issue.
https://forum.iredmail.org/topic16850-failed-to-receive-email-from-instagram.html

Comment: This sounds like more of a feature than a problem. Not seeing how it’s an Ubuntu-specific thing, though 

Comment: I was thinking more Ubuntu/Postfix config thing. Which is why I used those tags?

Comment: Does your server have implemented techniques like SPF, DKIM, DMARC and so on? Your firewall (network or server side) may be preventing  some IP addresses reaching your server also...

Comment: @FedonKadifeli  Im not sure to be hnest, but I will look into what they actualy are. And whether or not they could be blocking instagram. Im not a programmer so not sure n any of that. But there was some info in the original config: v=DKIM1; p= MIGfMA0GCSq-LONG-NUMBER-AND-TEXT-HERE
v=DMARC1; p=none; pct=100; rua=mailto:dmarc@mydomain.net

Comment: I think yes, as I get zipped reports to the dmark email address.